# Best database strategy of migration asp.net mvc project from enterprise to cloud (Azure is preferred)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

We built an ASP.NET MVC project (with EF) which were running on private servers of our customer, some big enterprises (let's call it the e edition). Now we want to build an edition which can be run on the clouds for other small companies (the c edition).

The e edition is quite straight forward: an ASP.NET MVC website with some `.mdf` files (SQL Server Express is just enough) in `App_data`.

For the c edition, there are some solutions:

For the website application itself:

1.1 Create each of the application as a standalone website --- which is costly and unmaintainable, so it's out of consideration.

1.2 A single website hosting services for all the enterprises, sounds good. (Am I right?)

For the database, it's quite complex.

2.1 Add "Enterprise Id" in all the tables. Sounds terrible because a. performance could be low. b. security is difficult to maintain. c. The code of e edition and the c edition would be different, because the new added Id.

2.2 Create different `App_Data` folders for each enterprise, the same website access different folders via programmatic Connection String. Both the website and tables are just same in e and c edition.

2.2 sounds great, but there is a big problem:
In clouds like Azure (with which I'm not familiar), I do not think that it has SQL Server Express running. Instead, those "different folders" would be "different db instances", which is very costly, considering that there might be hundreds of Trial enterprise. One way walking around is to rent an "old style host server", which is basically a virtual machine with windows server, so I can get SQL Server Express installed. But this really sounds not a fashion.

2.3 Create tables with programmatic prefix in names, so one db but many tables for different enterprises.
But there is another problem: I'm using EF code first, so all the name of the tables are defined in [Table("TableName")] before compiling.

After reading "[Migrating MVC application to AZure Appservice and Cloud Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45507561/migrating-mvc-application-to-azure-appservice-and-cloud-service)", I would say the Azure app service would be my first choice.

So, which one should be the best strategy or am I missing some better solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a matter of opinion and is likely to be closed. But a few things that you might not be aware of:

- The Elastic Database Client Library - helps in managing N different customer databases. I have not used this library personally. Take a [look here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-database-client-library).
- Elastic pools - If you do end up managing multiple databases, you don't have to pay rack rates per database. If spikes vary across clients, you can define and pay for an elastic pool of DTUs. All of your databases in the pool draw from this same pool. For lots and lots of databases, this can greatly reduce cost.The docs [are here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-pool).

Comment: Great, this should be what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot. I will investigate the Elastic pools. It sounds promising.